# How to read a file with delimitted name value pairs using DOS batch script?

Tags: file, dos

I have a file with each line of the format name=value. I need to read it using a DOS script and store all the name value pairs in memory. The names are from a predefined list of names, so I can have a list of DOS variables, and assign values to them as and when a line is read from the file.
Please provide the script for doing this. I'm not able to even do as much as read a file using the below code which I got on the internet, it printes nothing:
    FOR /F %i IN (regfort.properties) DO @echo %i

Comment: To run this from a batch script instead of the command prompt, double your percentage signs: `FOR /F %%i IN (regfort.properties) DO @echo %%i`. Be aware that this test only echoes the first token of each line…

Answer (score 3):

This is a very simple script that sets some environment variables (names prefixed with `prop_`) based on the name/value pairs in the specified file, i.e. *name=value* in the file becomes prop_*name=value* in the environment:

```
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%i IN (regfort.properties) DO set "prop_%%i=%%j"
```

Running `set prop_` will then display the names and values of all variables with name prefix `prop_`.